# Way to find points a certain distance on perpendicular lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Assuming I have two points $P1$ and $P2$, if I take a line between them, how would I get 4 points that are a certain distance $w$ away from $P1$ and $P2$ on perpendicular lines? If this is in a 3D coordinate space, and I want the plane to always be flat along the X and Z axis, what would I do?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udhoP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the vector between $P_1$ and $P_2$, perform the cross product with that vector and the plane normal you want the points to be on (In this case, $[0,1,0]$), then normalize that vector, scale it by the distance, then add the vector to the point.